# Sort array by first character then number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is list of object contains data like below:

```
[
    {name: 'Foo 1'},
    {name: 'Foo 14'},
    ..
    {name: 'Foo 2'},
    {name: 'Bar 1'},
    {name: 'Bar 15'},
    ...
    {name: 'Bar 2'},
]
```

I need to sort this as

```
[
    {name: 'Bar 1'},
    {name: 'Bar 2'},
    ...
    {name: 'Bar 15'},
    {name: 'Foo 1'},
    {name: 'Foo 1'},
    ...
    {name: 'Foo 12'},
]
```

With classic character sorting 'Foo 14' gets ahead of 'Foo 2' so I need to sort by letter and numbers.

value pattern: There might be multiple words but always ends with number like "word word .. number"

Comment: Is it always a word, then a space, and then a number?

Comment: Yes but word can be more than one, but it always ends with number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Collator#compare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare) for this. The `compare()` method compares two strings according to the sort order of the `Intl.Collator` object. Just make sure you pass an options object where you set `numeric` to `true`:

```js
const collator = new Intl.Collator("en", {
  numeric: true,
  sensitivity: "base",
});

const arr = [
  { name: "Foo 1" },
  { name: "Baz 21" },
  { name: "Foo 14" },
  { name: "Foo 2" },
  { name: "Bar 1" },
  { name: "Baz 10" },
  { name: "Bar 15" },
  { name: "Bar 2" },
  { name: "Baz 1" },
  { name: "Baz 2" },
];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.name, b.name));

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: it works perfect!

Comment: Nice answer! I would have done it with regex and do the logic myself, but this is much better. Nice to learn about collator and the numeric option

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works :)

Comment: twice faster than `localeCompare`. nice answer +1

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `Intl.Collator` is almost twice as fast as `localeCompare`. So, I would use @ZsoltMeszaros answer.

---

Using `String.prototype.localeCompare()`:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "Foo 1" },
  { name: "Baz 21" },
  { name: "Foo 14" },
  { name: "Foo 2" },
  { name: "Bar 1" },
  { name: "Baz 10" },
  { name: "Bar 15" },
  { name: "Bar 2" },
  { name: "Baz 1" },
  { name: "Baz 2" },
];

console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name,'en',{numeric : true})))
```